# retrieve an element from a collection firebase flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

im trying to retrieve an element from a collection in firebase for example i have a list of courses and i want to get MATH course from the list.

i did this to retrieve the hall collection but i dont know how to search and retrieve for one element only. please help

```
getDocumentData() async {
  CollectionReference _cat = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Courses");
  QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await _cat.get();
  final _docData = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data()).toList();
  print(_docData);
}
```

this is my database

[image]

Comment: How do you define the MATH course? Via a field? Can you show a screenshot of your database.,

Comment: i just posted it . thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To only get the course where `cName` is `MATH` you can [use a query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) (FlutterFire docs [here](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage#querying) and [here](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/Query/where.html)):

```
CollectionReference _cat = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Courses");
Query query = _cat.where("cName", isEqualTo: "MATH");
QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await query.get();
final _docData = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data()).toList();
```